# 16 bit hex into 14 bit signed int python?

Tags: python, cut, bit, data-conversion

I get a 16 bit Hex number (so 4 digits) from a sensor and want to convert it into a signed integer so I can actually use it.
There are plenty of codes on the internet that get the job done, but with this sensor it is a bit more arkward.

In fact, the number has only 14 bit, the first two (from the left) are irrelevant.
I tried to do it (in Python 3) but failed pretty hard.
Any suggestions how to "cut" the first two digits of the number and then make the rest a signed integer? 
The Datasheet says, that E002 should be -8190 ane 1FFE should be +8190.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As a side note: 'digit' is not the correct term. That is reserved for decimal numbers (Not hex)

Comment: thanks for correcting me Sinkingpoint! I'm not a native speaker, as far as I know, we don't have different terms for different number systems so I didn_t think about that. Good to know though and always good to learn something ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let's define a conversion function:

```
>>> def f(x):
...    r = int(x, 16)
...    return r if r < 2**15 else r - 2**16
...
```

Now, let's test the function against the values that the datahsheet  provided:

```
>>> f('1FFE')
8190
>>> f('E002')
-8190
```

The usual convention for signed numbers is that a number is negative if the high bit is set and positive if it isn't.  Following this convention, '0000' is zero and 'FFFF' is -1.  The issue is that `int` assumes that a number is positive and we have to correct for that:

- For any number equal to or less than `0x7FFF`, then high bit is unset and the number is positive.  Thus we return `r=int(x,16)` if r<2**15.
- For any number `r-int(x,16)` that is equal to or greater than `0x8000`, we return `r - 2**16`.
- While your sensor may only produce 14-bin data, the manufacturer is following the standard convention for 16-bit integers.

#### Alternative

Instead of converting `x` to `r` and testing the value of `r`, we can directly test whether the high bit in `x` is set:

```
>>> def g(x):
...    return int(x, 16) if x[0] in '01234567' else int(x, 16) - 2**16
... 
>>> g('1FFE')
8190
>>> g('E002')
-8190
```

#### Ignoring the upper bits

Let's suppose that the manufacturer is not following standard conventions and that the upper 2-bits are unreliable.  In this case, we can use modulo, `%`, to remove them and, after adjusting the other constants as appropriate for 14-bit integers, we have:

```
>>> def h(x):
...    r = int(x, 16) % 2**14
...    return r if r < 2**13 else r - 2**14
... 
>>> h('1FFE')
8190
>>> h('E002')
-8190
```

Comment: The issue you will (at least potentially) hit here with a *14* bit number is that bits 0xc000 are meant to be ignored, so that while 0xe002 is -8190, so is 0x2002.  If bits 14 and 15 are *copies* of the sign bit (bit 13), you're OK treating it as a signed 16-bit two's complement value.

Comment: @torek  True.  I would have been concerned about that except the manufacturer says that E002 is -8190: in other words, they are following standard conventions for 16-bit integers.

Comment: @torek For completeness, I just added code to ignore the upper 2 bits

Comment: thank you very much for solving my problem and for your explanation as well!

Answer (score 1):

There is a general algorithm for sign-extending a two's-complement integer value `val` whose number of bits is `nbits` (so that the top-most of those bits is the sign bit).

That algorithm is:

1. treat the value as a non-negative number, and if needed, mask off additional bits
2. invert the sign bit, still treating the result as a non-negative number
3. subtract the numeric value of the sign bit considered as a non-negative number, producing as a result, a *signed* number.

Expressing this algorithm in Python produces:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def sext(val, nbits):
    assert nbits > 0
    signbit = 1 << (nbits - 1)
    mask = (1 << nbits) - 1
    return ((val & mask) ^ signbit) - signbit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('sext(0xe002, 14) =', sext(0xe002, 14))
    print('sext(0x1ffe, 14) =', sext(0x1ffe, 14))
```

which when run shows the desired results:

```
sext(0xe002, 14) = -8190
sext(0x1ffe, 14) = 8190
```